# A monte e a valle cosa significano?

Tags: idioms, word-meaning

Nel libro di fisica c'è scritto:

> La differenza di potenziale tra un punto A e un punto B a valle
>   distante h è Eh, se il punto B è a monte è -Eh.

Il punto A e B devono essere su una linea. Consideriamo che sempre l'inizio è a sinistra e fine è a destra. Quindi quando possiamo dire che abbiamo Eh e quando possiamo dire che abbiamo -Eh? (Nel caso di AB o nel caso di BA)

Ho cercato sul Internet e ho visto che *a valle* vuol dire alla fine però questo mi porta a una contradizione. Così ho pensato che forse non capisco l'intera frase.

Comment: If any, un libro di fisica dove si scrive in quel modo è da buttare nel cestino.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Nel gergo della fisica ci sono diverse metafore che associano il potenziale al concetto di alto/basso, come per esempio "buca di potenziale" o "caduta di tensione". È un termine rischioso da usare in un libro di testo, specialmente se non è spiegato adeguatamente, ma è evocativo e tutto sommato favorisce l'idea intuitiva di potenziale che si vuole creare.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Nella fattispecie non è evocativo e favorisce solamente l'insorgere di dubbi; non è una metafora. Infatti l'utente non ha richiesto spiegazioni più prosaiche di un concetto scientifico su un sito di scienza, ma hai chiesto il significato in italiano di una frase che presumibilmente avrebbe dovuto essere scritta in italiano su un sito dedicato alla lingua

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*A monte* means (among others) *upstream*, *a valle* means (among others) *downstream*. This is obvious if you consider that rivers flow from mountain (*monte*) to valley (*valle*).

In your case *upstream* and *downstream* can hardly be used "as is" in the English version - a different wording is probably more appropriate.
The English translation could be something like:

> The potential difference (voltage) between a point A and a point B at a distance h in the direction of the electric field **E** is Eh. If the point B is in the opposite direction, it is -Eh.

The confusion seems to arise from the fact that the potential difference the book is talking of here is not V(B)-V(A), but V(A)-V(B). Point A, in the first situation depicted, is at a higher potential than point B.

You are not the only one confused by this text (apparently Mazzoldi, Nigro, Voci - "Elementi di Fisica - Elettromagnetismo", vol. 2), have a look [here](http://www.matematicamente.it/forum/a-valle-e-a-monte-significato-in-questo-caso-t80156.html).

Answer (score 0):

"A monte" identifies the beginning.

`A monte della lite` indicates a the beginning of discussion

"A valle" is the opposite point, so indicates the ending.

[Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_129.html)